# how to find all .bat files and execute them one by one?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, powershell-2.0

I am still very new to PowerShell and need some help.

I have some .bat files in a folder called: `c:\scripts\run\`
and I want to run them one by one but I don't know how many I have, it changes from time to time.

So I want to run a loop with `foreach` like this:

```
foreach ($file in get-childitem c:\scripts\run | where {$_.extension -eq ".bat"})
```

But I don't know how to run them now.
I know that I can run them 1 by 1 like this :

```
./run1.bat
./run2.bat
./run3.bat
```

But how do I implement that?
Thanks!!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
Get-Childitem -Path c:\scripts\run -Filter *.bat | % {& $_.FullName}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
& $file.FullName
```

within your loop.

I would probably just use a pipeline, though, instead of an explicit `foreach` loop:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\scripts\run -Filter *.bat | ForEach-Object { & $_.FullName }
```

If you want additional checks after each batch file ran:

```
gci C:\scripts\run -fi *.bat | % {
  & $_.FullName
  if (Test-Path C:\scripts\run\blah.log) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you as well. is there a way to check between every running bat file if the script was running successfully ? my scripts create log files, which i can possible check.

Comment: Sure, you have an entire block at your disposal within `ForEach-Object`.